# Background Image comes up as white when displayed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background image whenever the document is loaded, and when it hits this point:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('../images/mobile-bckground.png')";
```

The page simply makes the background plain white. It is displayed like this in my javascript:

```
$(function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('../images/mobile-bckground.png')";
});
```

I have verified the image is in the right location using this css:

```
body
{
    background-image:url('../images/mobile-bckground.png');
}
```

which displays it in the background correctly, why is it doing this?

Comment: try specifying 'background-position'!

Comment: is your image correct i.e. is `mobile-bckground.png` suppose to be `mobile-background.png` ?

Comment: Try removing the single quotes from within the url... ie. `backgroundImage="url(..images/mobile-bckground.png)"`

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: The image name is correct, like I said it worked with the above CSS. And I removed the single quotes and it still is displaying a white background

Comment: Can you post a link to an example or post the full code?

Comment: try `'url('./images/mobile-bckground.png')'` or an absolute url `'url('http://www.yoursite.com/images/mobile-bckground.png')'`

Comment: I just checked the console and it said Failed to load Resource. Why is this if it worked in the CSS? It shows it in the correct folder and everything.

Comment: @Andoid - see the update in my answer

Comment: Problem was solved by freefaller!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem will be down to the way in which CSS works.

If you reference a file within an external CSS file, then the position of the referenced files are **relative to the position of the external CSS file**.

If the CSS is within the HTML itself, then the position of the referenced files are **relative to the position of the HTML document**

So the path that works in the external CSS will not necessarily work directly in the HTML.

---

**Update**

If the value is being set by Javascript (either internal to the page, or held in an external file) then the position will still be based on the HTML page, and NOT the position of the CSS file or JS file

Comment: It is not in the HTML I am doing this. I have two folders, CSS and JS. The CSS folder holds the css file that I used to test the background image that worked. If that path worked, it should work in my js file that is in the JS folder as well right? Does ../ go up a folder then /images/mobile-bckground.png go in the image folder then to the image?

Comment: @Android, it's a fair assumtion, but the position of any external JS has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: You're right! I changed the path to /images/mobile-bckground.png and it worked! I was assuming the path was relative to the JS file, not the HTML file that loaded it. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome @Android, good luck with the rest of your project :-) Please remember to mark this answer as correct, as that helps the community to know the state of your question, and also provides us both with a bit more reputation